# Using gcc for compiling/converting, matrix.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, r, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I'm trying to convert some .c files to R files using gcc.
The files im talking about are circulant.c and circulant.h files located at:

http://www.columbia.edu/~ad3217/fbm.html

There the author also provided short instructions how to do it with gcc.
Things I did so far:

1. installed Ubuntu via the Win10 Linux Subsystem
2. installed build essentials
3. installed gcc
4. downloaded all meschach files from

   http://www.netlib.org/c/meschach/
5. putting the meschach folder and circulant.x files into one folder and running the command

   `$gcc -I meschach/ -c circulant.c`

gives the error:

```
In file included from circulant.c:25:0:
circulant.h:11:20: fatal error: matrix.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I hope that someone with more knowledge with gcc can help me out and point me to a solution.

Comment: It is apparently looking for some header called `matrix.h` that isn't there.

Comment: i tried locating it, and found the ccpmat library ([link](http://cppmat.geus.me/en/latest/) containing such a file but installing it gave just more errors of the same kind: `fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just some file named `matrix.h` won't do.  You'll need to use the one your project is expecting.  You'd have to ask the people responsible for the software about that.

Comment: I think I found the correct library as mentioned above, it should be cppmat. My problem now is to correctly install the library so that gcc includes it properly. at least i think it is some openly available library otherwise the author would have mentioned it.

Comment: If that is indeed the correct one, you can tell gcc where to look for headers with something like `-Ipath/to/header`

Comment: I did just that via `$gcc -I meschach/ -c cppmat/matrix.h -c cppmat/cppmat.h -c circulant.c` and got the ominous error: `cppmat/cppmat.h:12:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cppmat/cppmat.h:12:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from circulant.c:25:0:
circulant.h:11:20: fatal error: matrix.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`  which makes no sense to me 'algorithm' just sounds like a standard library to me

Comment: That's definitely not right.  You should not be passing in the headers to the compiler directly like that, and certainly not with the `-c` flag.  You just need to pass the path to the header files it should be searching.  like `-Icppmat` since that appears to be the directory where the header file exists.

Comment: I followed your advice and used`$gcc -Icppmat -Imeschach circulant.c`. the error now is shorter and the compiler only demands the 'algorithm' header. `In file included from cppmat/matrix.h:12:0,
                 from circulant.h:11,
                 from circulant.c:25:
cppmat/cppmat.h:12:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: in `/usr/include$ find . -name algorithm` I found some candidates. `gcc -Icppmat -Imeschach -I/usr/include/c++/5 circulant.c` now produces `/usr/include/c++/5/utility:68:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.` this is a somehow tedious procedure. is there no easier way doing this?

Comment: You are using the wrong library.  `cppmat` has nothing to do with this.  It just happens to have a filed named `matrix.h`.  You need to follow the installation steps for [meschach](http://www.netlib.org/c/meschach/) from the [README](http://www.netlib.org/c/meschach/readme). See my posted answer.  Good luck.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I responded to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the right header files.

You have some dependency issues you need to take care of first.  From the comment header block of [circulant.c](http://www.columbia.edu/~ad3217/fbm/circulant.c):

```
/*  This program simulates fractional Gaussian noise or fractional          */
/*  Brownian motion using the Wood and Chan algorithm.                      */
/*  The C-packages Ranlib and Meschach are used, both available             */
/*  via Netlib (http://www.netlib.org).                                     */
```

Looks to me like the missing `matrix.h` and `matrix2.h` files are from the [meschach](http://www.netlib.org/c/meschach/) library.

**You can't just copy the `.shar` files into a directory.**

You need to read the [README](http://www.netlib.org/c/meschach/readme) file and follow the installation instructions. So I would recommend installing the [ranlib](http://www.netlib.org/random/) and [meschach](http://www.netlib.org/c/meschach/) dependencies first.

Comment: Thank you. This was the correct approach. `$ gcc -Imeschach -c -Iranlib -c circulant.c
In file included from circulant.h:11:0,
                 from circulant.c:25:
meschach/matrix.h:181:8: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘m_free’ [-Wimplicit-int]...` seems to be working with just some warnings. Now I get for the second command however `$gcc -shared -fPIC -Imeschach -o circulant.so circulant.o /meschach/meschach.a -lm
gcc: error: /meschach/meschach.a: No such file or directory`.

Comment: probably needs to be `.... circulant.o meschach/meschach.a -lm` -- ie: no "/" at the front of the path -- because you don't have a "/" on the path at `-Imeschach`

Comment: `gcc -shared -fPIC -Imeschach -o circulant.so circulant.o meschach/meschach.a -lm` gives
`/usr/bin/ld: circulant.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
circulant.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` and `gcc -fPIC -Imeschach -o circulant.so circulant.o meschach/meschach.a -lm` yields a myriad of other undefined references. at this point I'm probably better of quitting